# sharp-repository custom repositories with structuremap

Tags: c#, structuremap, sharp-repository

Using StructureMap 3.0.3.116 to initialize services with custom IRepository<,> with SharpRepository, structuremap still cannot find concrete class using the default convention.

```
public interface IBlogImageRepository : IRepository<BlogImage,int>
{
}

public class BlogImageRepository : 
    ConfigurationBasedRepository<BlogImage, int>, IBlogImageRepository
{
```

Error:

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically
>   determined for type 'My.Assembly.Repositories.IBlogImageRepository'

```
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.Assembly("S3.Libs");
            scan.IncludeNamespace("S3.Libs.Repositories");
            scan.IncludeNamespace("S3.Libs.Services");
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IRepository<,>));
        });
        x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please show your configuration.

Comment: Can you post any inner exception details as a lot of times that gives more specific information as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I got it to work by adding [DefaultConstructor] attribute to the constructor that had no parameters.  It was trying to use the greediest constructor.

http://docs.structuremap.net/UsingAttributes.htm#section2

Answer (score 0):

It might be that it is actually throwing the exception when trying to create the IRepository<,> within the IBlogImagerepository as opposed to not being able to find the IBlogImageRepository interface itself.  The inner exception might give more details.

I would try using the [SharpRepository.Ioc.StructureMap](http://nuget.org/packages/SharpRepository.Ioc.StructureMap/) NuGet package and then adding

```
x.ForRepositoriesUseSharpRepository();
```

to your initialization method and seeing if this helps.